# Install directory for rpm made with setup.py (setuptools)

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools, setup.py

I need to deploy a python project with `rpm` package. I make it with `setuptools` library:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

After command `rpm -i myapp.rpm` performed application installs to the directory `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`. However, I need to install my application to another folder `/foo/`. How can I gain it?

Comment: python plugins are always installed in /usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages. You can have a subdirectory using `package_dir = {'subdir', ''}` in your setup.py

Comment: @ChrisMaes - Thank you. Did you mean that it's impossible to install `myapp` to folder `/foo/`? By the way, my application isn't a plugin.

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible; I just know that usually it installs in /usr/lib/... I'm not that used to it; I just know how to use it as plugins, not as executables for example..

Comment: @ChrisMaes - Thank you, anyway. What python plugin is?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to install rpm to folder `/foo/lib/python/`:

Make `setup.cfg` available in `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
...

setup(
   ...
   setup_cfg=True,
   ...
)
```

Create `setup.cfg` in the same directory as `setup.py` with the following text:

```
[install]
home=/foo/
```